# Are there things you can do with Expression Blend that you can't do with regular WPF?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, expression-blend

I know that Blend does make things easier. But does it have any extra libraries available to it that give it more functionality? Or that allow things that can’t be done with regular WPF through Visual Studio?

Thanks?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, this question is not a good fit for Stack Overflow as it is soliciting opinions - we deem this to be overly chatty, as discussed in the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). You can read the FAQ to see what kinds of questions are a better fit.

Comment: Really? Its a question that has a quantifiable answer. I'm not asking for an opinion.

Comment: Oded: I couldn't disagree more. The question of whether or not Blend has capabilities beyond traditional WPF/XAML is purely factual.  A statement such as "I would rather be poked in the eye with a sharp stick than hand code XAML without Blend", for instance, is opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, no: there's nothing that Blend can do that you can't do yourself.  Blend is basically just producing Xaml markup, which you can always produce by hand in Notepad if you choose to (let alone Visual Studio).

However, there are a number of things that Blend as a UI is much better suited to creating/editing - foremost in my mind are animations, which have nice pretty timeline support in Blend versus hand-typing markup in the VS designer (at least in VS2010, I'm not sure about VS2012).

There are a couple of Xml namespaces that Blend will include in your markup for its own purposes (typically to make the designer behave better).  If you're a hand-editor of Xaml these are an annoyance (IMO), but they're certainly *available* to you still if you wanted to use them.

Comment: Thank you. That's the info I was interested in.

Answer (score 6):

The important libraries like `Interactivity` are redistributable, otherwise you would have quite some problems making use of what you did with Blend. But as they are just libraries nothing stops you from using them without Blend. Blend is a tool to make things easier just like Visual Studio, you need neither to write an application.

The product of those tools is always code (and possibly binaries), so in that sense there is nothing that only Blend can do but that is beside the point.